# Duplicate class com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest found in modules

Tags: android, gradle, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to migrate to drive v3 api for my android app and I have followed instructions provided inhttps://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/tree/master/drive/deprecation to migrate. I am getting dependency resolution errors.

I have used duplicate classes shown in log in exclude option but it haven't worked

list of my drive api dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.29.1'

    implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.28.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }

    implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev99-1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
 }
```

Below are the error lines shown

```
Duplicate class com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest found in modules google-http-client-1.29.1.jar (com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.29.1) and google-http-client-apache-2.0.0.jar (com.google.http-client:google-http-client-apache:2.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpResponse found in modules google-http-client-1.29.1.jar (com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.29.1) and google-http-client-apache-2.0.0.jar (com.google.http-client:google-http-client-apache:2.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport found in modules google-http-client-1.29.1.jar (com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.29.1) and google-http-client-apache-2.0.0.jar (com.google.http-client:google-http-client-apache:2.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.client.http.apache.ContentEntity found in modules google-http-client-1.29.1.jar (com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.29.1) and google-http-client-apache-2.0.0.jar (com.google.http-client:google-http-client-apache:2.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.client.http.apache.HttpExtensionMethod found in modules google-http-client-1.29.1.jar (com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.29.1) and google-http-client-apache-2.0.0.jar (com.google.http-client:google-http-client-apache:2.0.0)
```

Comment: how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message:

```
found in modules google-http-client-1.29.1.jar
```

it seems to reference:

```
implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.29.1'
```

Based upon the version number. Have you tried to exclude the library from that artefact too?

Comment: Ah, I didn't read it carefully enough. I think you have the wrong exclusion tag.
You see it is called:  X:Y:Z, where X is the Group, Y the artefact and Z the version.

On 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.29.1' you should exclude:

group: com.google.http-client

And not org.apache.httpcomponents